Exim not authenticating for sending email
I have updated my Exim (on Directadmin) to version 4.97.1
In the process something went wrong and now i can't send e-mails any more.
I can receive email (remote and using LMTP with Dovecot).
Also i found out this morning that local mail is also working fine. root -> exim -> dovecot.
When using an remote e-mail application i get (tested both plain and login):
2024-04-15 07:51:01 plain authenticator failed for dynamic.caiway.nl ([192.168.178.2]) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mail@example.com)
2024-04-14 09:12:29 login authenticator failed for dynamic.caiway.nl ([192.168.178.2]) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mail@example.com)

I get different results for using port 25 or port 587. but the certificates are okay:
telnet server.example.com 25
Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
Connected to server.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.example.com ESMTP Exim 4.97.1 Mon, 15 Apr 2024 08:18:19 +0200
ehlo caiway.nl
250-server.example.com Hello dynamic.caiway.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPECONNECT
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

It says STARTTLS and AUTH PLAIN LOGIN, so that's good i believe.
But when connecting through openssl with starttls on port 587 i get:
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect server.example.com:587 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)

nothing more, when connecting through openssl on port 25 i get:
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect server.example.com:25 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1

Server certificate
subject=CN = example.com
issuer=C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 6202 bytes and written 434 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 HELP

Also the EHLO on port 587 when using telnet just disconnects:
telnet server.example.com 587
Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
Connected to server.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
ehlo caiway.nl
Connection closed by foreign host.

some logs from the above testing are like:
2024-04-15 08:19:18 TLS error on connection from dynamic.caiway.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (SSL_accept): (TLSv1.3)
2024-04-15 08:20:21 TLS error (SSL_read): on connection from dynamic.caiway.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
2024-04-15 08:21:07 TLS error on connection from dynamic.caiway.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (SSL_accept): error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

I'm kinda lost, i first thought it was an certificate issue. but openssl on port 25 with -showcerts shows all certificates are okay.
Exim is advertising AUTH and STARTTLS.
but on connect trough port 587 just disconnects.
My Exim config shows all the right values (i believe):
auth_advertise_hosts = ${if or { {eq {$received_port}{465}} {eq {$received_port}{587}} } {*}{}}
auth_advertise_hosts = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
daemon_smtp_ports=25:587:465
tls_on_connect_ports=587:465

EDIT---- ADDITIONAL INFO:
from running exim in debug mode with output i get this when connecting from mail client to send an email.
19:38:10 111203 login authenticator server_condition:
19:38:10 111203   $auth1 = mail@example.com
19:38:10 111203   $auth2 = password
19:38:10 111203   $1 = mail@example.com
19:38:10 111203   $2 = password
19:38:10 111203  ╭considering: ${perl{smtpauth}{0}}
19:38:10 111203   ╭considering: smtpauth}{0}}
19:38:10 111203   ├───────text: smtpauth
19:38:10 111203   ├considering: }{0}}
19:38:10 111203   ├──expanding: smtpauth
19:38:10 111203   ╰─────result: smtpauth
19:38:10 111203   ╭considering: 0}}
19:38:10 111203   ├───────text: 0
19:38:10 111203   ├considering: }}
19:38:10 111203   ├──expanding: 0
19:38:10 111203   ╰─────result: 0
19:38:10 111203 Starting Perl interpreter
19:38:10 111203  ├──expanding: ${perl{smtpauth}{0}}
19:38:10 111203  ╰─────result: 0
19:38:10 111203 expanded string: 0
19:38:10 111203  ╭considering: $1
19:38:10 111203  ├──────value: mail@example.com
19:38:10 111203             ╰──(tainted)
19:38:10 111203  ├──expanding: $1
19:38:10 111203  ╰─────result: mail@example.com
19:38:10 111203             ╰──(tainted)
19:38:10 111203 SMTP>> 535 Incorrect authentication data

Still no real world info here.
Any advice? I'm kinda lost and don't know where to start/look.

okay i have found the issue..
apparently the configured Login and Plain authentication methods don't work any more.
i saw in the debug output amongst the Authenticators was dovecot.
so that made me think and i found this article:
Exim and Dovecot SASL
changing this and it worked flawless.
